# Scanner input to calculate interest, principle and total

Tags: java, loops

I got a question regarding to scanner input, it asks to calculate principle, interest and total for 10 years, the code is:

```
package random;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

        System.out.print("The principle is ");
        double principle = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("The interest rate is ");
        double interestRate = input.nextDouble();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            double Interest = principle * interestRate;
            double Total = principle + Interest;
            principle = Total - Interest;
            System.out.println("Year " + i + " principle: " + "$" + Total + " " + "Interest:            " + "$" + Interest + " " +
                "Total: " + "$" + Total);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run it, it shows:

```
       The principle is 10000.00
       The interest rate is 0.05
       Year 1 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 2 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 3 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 4 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 5 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 6 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 7 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 8 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 9 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
       Year 10 principle: $10500.0 Interest: $500.0 Total: $10500.0
```

I think the problem is from my loop, could anyone advise? Cheers!

Comment: Naming convention for variable in Java : if the name consists of only one word, spell that word in lowercase. If it consists of more than one word, capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. Example: `variable` `oneVariable`. So `Interest` and `Total` should be `interest` and `total`

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
principle= Total-Interest;
```

Is the same as:

```
principle=principle;
```

since:

```
double Total=principle+Interest;
```

And so your calculation never reduces principle.

You need to first calculate the monthly payment using the standard amortization formulas (which I assume must have been given to you), then subtract out the interest to see how much principle is being payed.

Comment: hi, thank you for reply, the formulas are interest=principle*interestRate,total=principle+interest, but my problem is about design the principle and total

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer: consider posting your actual assignment. I'm thinking that you'd use the standard amortization formulas such as those that can be found on [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_(business)).